# Send invites from the app itself

Tags: facebook, invite

How can we send Facebook invites to users of our application?
Usually we receive invites only from friends but not directly from the app itself.

I received an invite from The Sims Social a few months ago and I want to develop the same thing, here is a screenshot:

[image: Sims invite]

Answer (score 0):

This kind of request is known as an [App to User Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#app_to_user). Only apps that are on Facebook.com or mobile apps can use and send these kinds of requests. Sending them is pretty simple, just make an HTTP POST request to `/USER_ID/apprequests` with your app access token. You will also want to handle deleting them once they are accepted by the user and reading a list of current requests. They're all documented in the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests) docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain application access token then you can send to the users who are the using this app.

FYI: A[uthenticating as an App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/)